# Python dealing with months and years in arrays

Tags: python, arrays, datetime, time

newbie question,

I have three arrays, one with years, one with months and one with my data.

The years array has which year the data occurs in, but as the data is collected monthly, I have a lot of repeat years, eg `[1996,1997,...,1997,1998,...,1998,1999 etc]`

Then in the array I have `[01,02,...,11,12,01,02, etc]`

Is there anyway to amalgamate these two arrays into one, and then plot them vs my data?

I have tried multiplying the second array by `1/12` and adding it to the first array, but would prefer a more elegant solution. Any tips?

Thank you.

Comment: How do you want to merge them? What is the expected output?

Comment: Would you please post your arrays for us? Enter a new line and hit space four times and then type them out. It's easier for everyone to see their best solution when they don't have to visualize your work *and* theirs, you know?

Comment: It all depends on what you want to do with the array later, and on why you think having the two arrays are not the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `zip` to combine the years and months into `datetime.date` objects:

```
dates = [DT.date(y,m,1) for y, m in zip(years, months)]
```

To plot using [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as DT
import numpy as np

years = [1996]+[1997]*12+[1998]*12
months =[12]+range(1,13)+range(1,13)

dates = [DT.date(y,m,1) for y, m in zip(years, months)]
values = np.random.random(len(dates))

plt.plot(dates, values)
plt.show()
```

[image]